# DependencyProperty problems

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, designer

i'm confused.

I'm creating a control with dependencyProperties, it's not a properties that I can binding in my control, but I need to change my control's view if properties changes and show it in design mode too.

I've made PropertyChangedCallback and it works if something changes. BUT! If I open my form whew this control used, there is some value in this properties - nothing changed in Design window... if I change something - PropertyChangedCallback fired and I can see updates in Design window.

But it's not the only problem - after compiling and running my app, if none of it's properties changed from C# code - my control won't be updated :( What I suppose to do? How to create my properties in right way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps post some code of your control for members to review?